# How to use NLog's MutexMultiProcessFileAppender?

Tags: nlog

I failed to find any information about using this appender implementation (e.g. how to configure it in NLog.config). Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you configure the file target to use ConcurrentWrites, the MutexMultiProcessFileAppender will be used